# Add a secondary menu to my wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am trying to add a secondary menu to my Wordpress website. My goal is to display it at the very top of my website (https://cadinwebsite.wpcomstaging.com/), above the logo.

I have installed code snippets plugin and inserted the following code:

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

The code above works correctly and creates a new menu location in my "menus" dashboard.
But then, when I add the code below to display the newly created menu, my website crashes.

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
?>
```

I also tried to input the second part of my code in the header section, but it doesn't work either. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Could you also more of the file where you are using the wp_nav_menu

Comment: I get a "critical error" message.

Comment: I tried to input the wp_nav_menu code in the plugin Code Snippets, which is when it gives me a critical error. I have also tried to input that same code in the Insert Headers and Footers plugin but it does not display properly.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked and you made mistake in your add action code, please check with below code, and try with that

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'my-custom-menu', __( 'My Custom Menu', 'theme-text-domain' ) );
}

wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' 
) );
```